# Why `gets_s()` still isn't implemented in GCC (9.3.0)?

Tags: c, gcc, c11, gets

I know `fgets()` is a more common and widespread option for string input, but C11 has been around for 9 years. Why is `gets_s()` still out of work?

Even when I add `-std=c11`, it still doesn't work, even though `gets_s()` should be in `stdio.h`.

Comment: `gets_s` is optional in C11. There's no requirement for any compiler to implement that and AFAIK `gcc` does not.

Comment: Just use `fgets()`, which unlike `gets_s()`, is actually portable outside of MSVC.

Comment: Note that gcc is just a compiler and doesn't implement any stdio functions at all.  So your question is why your system's standard C library doesn't implement it, but you haven't said what system that is.  Anyway, gcc and its authors are not to blame.

Comment: As far as I know, **no one** implements all the Annex K functions as standardized.  Not even Microsoft, who was the principal behind their introduction.  Microsoft's version is similar, but not identical.  I also don't know many people outside Microsoft's influence who think these optional functions provide much genuine advantage, and few, if any, C implementations other than Microsoft's implement them at all.

Comment: The standard itself recommends fgets over gets_s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's optional. And the persons behind `gcc` seems to think it is a bad idea to include it. I don't know how they reasoned, but hints can be found in the C standard:

> **Recommended practice**
>
> The fgets function allows properly-written programs to safely process input lines too long to store in the result array. In general this requires that callers of fgets pay attention to the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array. Consider using fgets (along with any needed processing based on new-line characters) instead of gets_s.

[https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.4.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.4.1)

If you want to use `gets_s`, then use another compiler. Or write your own wrapper, but don't call it `gets_s` because it's quite tricky to get it completely identical to the specs.

The C standard says this:

> **Runtime-constraints**
>
> `s` shall not be a null pointer. `n` shall neither be equal to zero nor be greater than `RSIZE_MAX`. A new-line character, end-of-file, or read error shall occur within reading `n-1` characters from stdin.
>
> If there is a runtime-constraint violation, s[0] is set to the null character, and characters are read and discarded from stdin until a new-line character is read, or end-of-file or a read error occurs.
>
> **Description**
>
> The `gets_s` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by stdin, into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is discarded) or after end-of-file. The discarded new-line character does not count towards number of characters read. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.
>
> If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, or if a read error occurs during the operation, then `s[0]` is set to the null character, and the other elements of s take unspecified values.

There is one thing here that does not make sense at all. A runtime constraint is that `s` should not be a null pointer. On runtime constraint violoations, `s[0]` should be set to zero. But the operation `s[0] = '\0'` has undefined behavior if `s` is a null pointer.

Here is my take on trying to implement it, but IMO the specs are a mess, and I would not trust this. It was tricky to get it right.

```
char *my_gets_s(char *s, size_t n)
{
    if(!s) return NULL;

    size_t i=0;
    int ch;

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        ch = fgetc(stdin);

        // If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array,                          
        // or if a read error occurs during the operation, then s[0] is set to the null character                  
        if(ferror(stdin) || (ch == EOF && i == 0)) {
            s[0] = '\0';
            return NULL;
        }

        // If EOF and we have read at least one character                                                          
        if(ch == EOF) {
            s[0] = '\0';
            return s;
        }

        s[i] = ch;

        if(ch == '\n') {
            s[i] = '\0';
            return s;
        }
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    s[0] = '\0';
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Variable `c` is undeclared. Souldn't it be `ch` instead and `int ch;` outside loop?

Comment: @Jorengarenar I just realized it was trickier than I thought so I removed it :D

Comment: Yeah, I've just read the standard and no wonder compilers don't bother with it

Comment: @Jorengarenar I think I got it right now, but yeah, those specs were ... interesting...

Comment: @Jorengarenar: I find it rather bizarre that the C Standard has added new ways of handling console input, but has yet to provide any support for interactive applications that's better than building one's own routines based upon `getchar()`.  I suppose people have been building functions based on `getchar()` for so long there's little need for the Standard to provide nice built-in functions, but the language would be a lot nicer for newcomers if there were some decent console I/O support.

Comment: @supercat Late response, but I suspect that it at least partially is due to that C aims to work on such a huge range of computers. AFIK, the standard does not assume that you have neither a keyboard nor a monitor. It only assumes that there exist an input and an output stream.

Comment: @klutt: Any implementation should be able to support a function that would indicate what kinds of interactive I/O it supports.  While interactive consoles aren't universal, portability would be enhanced far more by providing a standard means of utilizing common features on platforms that support them, than by having the Standard exclude from its consideration everything that isn't universally supportable.

Comment: @supercat Well, I don't know. After all, C is not really the language of choice when it comes to applications with heavy user interaction. And I don't think "being beginner friendly" is a very strong argument to extend the standard. IMHO, the biggest problem is that beginners classes relies to much on writing programs requiring user input.

Comment: @klutt: In what sense would C not be the language of choice for writing a program like `more`, or even something like `vi` on a system which is expected to be used with a known variety of serial-connected terminals?  If one wants to write a text editor that will work with a serial-connected VT100, one shouldn't need to know any platform-specific details of what sits between the program and the terminal.

Comment: @supercat I don't deny that you have a point. I'm not just very convinced how important it is.

Comment: @klutt: On many systems, the primary purpose of most programs is to interact with a user via terminal interface.  While there are some systems where many programs would need something beyond a basic terminal interface, support for basic terminal I/O would have massively increased the range of practical applications that could be written to run on many platforms interchangeably from a small minority to a vast majority.

Answer (score 2):

While it would be useful to have an alternative to `fgets()` which will always read an entire line, discarding excess information if need be, and report how many characters were read, `gets_s` is not such a function.  The `gets_s` function would only be appropriate in scenarios in which any over-length input lines should be completely discarded.  The only good ways of performing line-based I/O are either to build one's own line-input routine based upon `fgetc()` or `getchar()`, use `fgets()` with corner-case logic that's as big as a character-based get-line routine, or--if one wants to maximize performance and the stream doesn't have to be shared with anything else--use `fread()` and `memchr()`, persisting read data in a private buffer between calls to the get-line routine.